# Python dataframe = Replace values in column string with values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, replace

I have the following dataframe (RuleDF) with a column which contains a string. 
Inside the string are some values (parameters) which shall be replaced 
eg. param1 and param2

| Rule_ID | Rule_Value |
| --- | --- |
| R-123 | column1 > param1 and column2 > param2 |
| R-456 | column1 > param1 |
| ... | ... |

There is another Dataframe (RuleMapDF) with the mapping:

| Rule_ID | Rule_Param | Param_Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| R-123 | param1 | 100 |
| R-123 | param2 | 200 |
| R-456 | param1 | 100 |

The result of the replacement will be something like this:
Another option is to have a new column with the replaced string

| Rule_ID | Rule_Value |
| --- | --- |
| R-123 | column1 > 100 and column2 > 200 |
| R-456 | column1 > 100 |
| ... | ... |

I appreciate any ideas.
Thank you.

Comment: do you tried the proposed solution? It's important to accept (only) if an answer fits to your need. From SO: "Accepting a solution will mark your question as resolved and will make it easier for others in the Community to find valuable content and answers without having to read through an entire topic"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Nk03, first create a mapping dict for each Rule_ID from df2 to allow string substitution with `replace()` method:

```
params = df2.groupby('Rule_ID') \
            .apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['Rule_Param'], x['Param_Value'].astype(str)))) \
            .to_dict()

out = df1.groupby('Rule_ID') \
         .apply(lambda x: x['Rule_Value'].replace(params[x.name], regex=True))
```

```
>>> params
{'R-123': {'param1': '100', 'param2': '200'}, 'R-456': {'param1': '100'}}

>>> out
Rule_ID
R-123    0    column1 > 100 and column2 > 200
R-456    1                      column1 > 100
Name: Rule_Value, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

One Way:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2.groupby('Rule_ID').apply(lambda x: dict(
    x[['Rule_Param', 'Param_Value']].values)).reset_index(), on='Rule_ID', how='left')
df3['Rule_Value'] = df3.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(
    str(x[0].get(i, i)) for i in x['Rule_Value'].split()), 1)
df3 = df3.drop(0, 1)
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
 Rule_ID                       Rule_Value
0   R-123  column1 > 100 and column2 > 200
1   R-456                    column1 > 100
```

###### 1st Step:

It will create a mapping dict for each `Rule_ID` from df2. We can `left merge` the result with the original `df1`.

```
  Rule_ID                             Rule_Value  \
0   R-123  column1 > param1 and column2 > param2   
1   R-456                       column1 > param1   

                                0  
0  {'param1': 100, 'param2': 200}  
1                 {'param1': 100}
```

###### 2nd Step:

It'll use the mapping dict to replace the value in the `Rule_Value` column.

###### 3rd step:

Drop the `map_dict` column i.e column `0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're updating every string in the `Rule_Value` column

```
dataframe.at[index,'Rule_Value']='new value'
```